# cannot resolve org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl

Tags: java, jpa

I keep getting an error saying:

```
cannot resolve org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
```

[image: 1]

My jar file is there but I am having a hard time trying to figure out why I am still getting the error:

[image: 2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="dataBase">

        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/springpractice"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="root"/>
            <!--<property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>-->
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE, Tool=INFO"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have look all over google and the answer is not there. I double check to make sure the dependencies are not there twice in case there was a conflict. Because of this when I try to declare a @Entity it is not picking up the database tables.

Comment: Do you have a jar specifically relating to OpenJPA? The Jar you've highlighted above is *just* an API; there is no implementation in javax.persistence.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import a JPA implementation jar (OpenJPA in this case). You could get one from [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.openjpa/openjpa/2.4.0) or [Apache OpenJPA home page itself](http://openjpa.apache.org/downloads.html).

UPDATED: as it has been mentioned in [another ansewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32235345/4680812) it's better to remove the other JPA provider libraries (Hibernate).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the images of your lib directory, I would say you the XML definition for `persistence-unit`>`provider` is not as expected.

There are Hibernate Jars in your lib, so it seem like that 
"Persistence Provider" should be "Hibernate", and not "Apache OpenJPA".

If you really want to use Apache OpenJPA, then I would recommend removing Hibernate Jar files in your lib.

Hibernate is more popular of the two, so I would recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following jar:

org.apache.openjpa:com.springsource.org.apache.openjpa.persistence:1.02

I trusted my IDE to much that it would download all the jars that I needed.

Comment: Yeah, maybe IDEs will be smart enough one day to know that that class as the provider in your persistence.xml means it should download the OpenJPA jar, but we're not there yet. Not to mention that the IDE would have no way of knowing what version to download. Now, if you use Maven or Gradle (or something like that) then the build process would be smart enough to do this...